# Why is Windows XP Remote Desktop no longer working?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a PC running Windows XP which acts as a bit of a server. There are 3 users which can be accessed remote desktop concurrently... until now. Recently when I remote desktop, it shows the Win XP login screen, lets you log in, and then says logging off just before the desktop begins to render.

I am trying to access the windows xp computer from a windows 8 pc, which has in the past worked. There has been no known recent changes to this computer, it was working, then it randomly restarted and instantly it was noticed that it was not working any more. Nothing else on the machine seems changed.

I have tried to create a new user, scan for viruses, check the disk, check the event logs, connect from a different PC, check the running services and have tried to find the error in the registry.

I have narrowed it down to the Windows remote desktop only because I can log in locally with a screen directly connected to the server. Also if I do log in locally, only then can I remote desktop to that user and take over, so somewhere in the remote desktop logging in process there is an error.

Why is this no longer working?

Comment: What OS are you trying to remote desktop from?

Comment: Has there been ANY recent changes to the Windows XP PC?

Comment: @CharlesH Windows 8

Comment: Try to create a new user on WinXP desktop (or delete profile folder). May be something broken in user registry,

Comment: @user498454 If you run /admin (or /console) after mstsc from Windows 8 command prompt to connect like this: mstsc /v:windowsxpmachinename /admin then login that way does that work?

Comment: @CharlesH Nope, doesn't make difference

Comment: @user498454 Do you have any machine older than Windows 8 to test with? I'm thinking a recent patch for Windows 8 could have updated the mstsc client to make it incompatible as Windows 10 will not remote desktop to Windows XP (as I found out recently to much annoyance)

Comment: @CharlesH I have a windows 7 PC which does the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

A possibly related problem, though on Windows Server 2008: [RDP update](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a520543-29d4-4466-9967-e39d819d11f1/users-cannot-log-into-remote-desktop-after-3112015-update)

> After removing KB3046049 and KB3002657 and rebooting the affected Servers TWICE the issue has been resolved.

Try uninstalling any updates that have been installed on either PC since it last worked.

Comment: The last updates that were installed are way back from 2012.